# PIC to measure Pressure sensor "MBS 1200"

Tags: pic, sensor, current-signal

I have a pressure sensor **MBS 1200**. I want to connect the same to a PIC micro controller for an application. Can you please suggest a circuit to do the same. I am not familiar with current output sensors. The datasheet is included here,

http://www.ra.danfoss.com/TechnicalInfo/Literature/Manuals/04/ICPDP21A702.pdf

Comment: You specified a product family, not a specific part. They have different interfaces, and would result in different circuits.

Comment: If you can choose one of the output options I suggest the radiometric one. Saves you from haeving a voltage reference at the PIC side.

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 versions of MBS1200.
 The current loop one is only one of the options.
 Please advise the fi=ull code on your unit so we can be sure of which versio you have - see table below.

If you do have the current loop version you need to tell us what power supply you have available. See table and chart at top of page 3. You need at least 8 volts and 2 or more would be better.

Report back ...

[image]